# lxml - Access value of meta tag on element

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have the following XML element:

```
<AdditionalAttribute name="Internal Version Identifier" value="UCV261KSBQGBPYF6" dataType="String"></AdditionalAttribute>
```

There are many of these tags, I would like to target this one specifically. An example of some of the tags is this:

```
<AdditionalAttribute name="Version Notes" value="This Item was released indirectly as a result of releasing Item 10X9061-11 to In Design." dataType="String"></AdditionalAttribute>
<AdditionalAttribute name="Change Number" value="BCV2386079506" dataType="String"></AdditionalAttribute>
<AdditionalAttribute name="Version Shared" value="No" dataType="String"></AdditionalAttribute>
<AdditionalAttribute name="Effective Version Shared" value="No" dataType="String"></AdditionalAttribute>
<AdditionalAttribute name="Material Effectivity Date" value="2016-03-15T08:52:33-08:00" dataType="String"></AdditionalAttribute>

<AdditionalAttribute name="Internal Version Identifier" value="UCV261KSBQGBPYF6" dataType="String"></AdditionalAttribute>                    
<AdditionalAttribute name="Item Creation Date" value="2016-03-01T09:08:14-08:00" dataType="String"></AdditionalAttribute>
```

I am using lxml and xpath to try and query all additional attributes for "Internal Version Identifier", once I have the element I need to extract the value from the 'value' field.

I want to find the AdditionalAttribute element whose name="Internal Version Identifier" and then get the value in the 'value' field.

I have been trying a few different things but unable to get the value I need:

Here is my current xpath query:

```
tree.xpath('//AdditionalAttribute[starts-with(text(), "Internal")]')
```

Comment: To be clear, the attribute whose value is `"Internal Version Identifier"` might be named `name`, or it might be named something else. Is that right?

Comment: Updated question to be more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `//AdditionalAttribute[@name="Internal Version Identifier"]`.

Tested example:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.XML('''
<root>
<AdditionalAttribute name="Version Notes" value="This Item was released indirectly as a result of releasing Item 10X9061-11 to In Design." dataType="String"></AdditionalAttribute>
<AdditionalAttribute name="Change Number" value="BCV2386079506" dataType="String"></AdditionalAttribute>
<AdditionalAttribute name="Version Shared" value="No" dataType="String"></AdditionalAttribute>
<AdditionalAttribute name="Effective Version Shared" value="No" dataType="String"></AdditionalAttribute>
<AdditionalAttribute name="Material Effectivity Date" value="2016-03-15T08:52:33-08:00" dataType="String"></AdditionalAttribute>

<AdditionalAttribute name="Internal Version Identifier" value="UCV261KSBQGBPYF6" dataType="String"></AdditionalAttribute>
<AdditionalAttribute name="Item Creation Date" value="2016-03-01T09:08:14-08:00" dataType="String"></AdditionalAttribute>
</root>
''')

elements = tree.xpath('//AdditionalAttribute[@name="Internal Version Identifier"]')
assert len(elements) == 1
assert elements[0].attrib["value"] == 'UCV261KSBQGBPYF6'
```

Alternatively, if you are only interested in `value` and not the entire element:

```
elements = tree.xpath(
    '//AdditionalAttribute[@name="Internal Version Identifier"]/@value')

assert len(elements) == 1
assert elements[0] == 'UCV261KSBQGBPYF6'
```

Comment: That worked thank you very much! I assume I can use @ + attribute name to target it, or is that strictly limited to attributes like name and value?

Comment: Your assumption is correct. The syntax `@FOO` always refers to the attribute named FOO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `//AdditionalAttribute/@value`;
It will grab: `value="UCV261KSBQGBPYF6"`

Comment: I should have clarified there are many AdditionalAttribute's, I was hoping to be able to target this one specifically without having to loop through all of them

Comment: How many do you have, you can always use `//*[n]` to grab the nth element of that type.

Comment: Updated question with an example of some of them, there is not a static number, at time there could be as ew as 10 and other times 100's